# System.DateTimeOffset in your WCF proxy conflicts with System.DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy, datetimeoffset

I generated a WCF proxy using svcutil when I tried to compile the file it generated the error(warning as error which I can't disable) that 
System.DateTimeOffset in your =proxy conficts with System.DateTimeOffset. I saw the proxy file it has DateTimeOffset. I used svctutil 4.0.30319.18052 to generate the proxy.

How to avoid this compilation error without disabling the check ? Application that uses the proxy is targeted for .net 4.0 version.
svcutil documentation at msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx mentions:

*"If DateTimeOffset referenced, this type is used instead of generating a new type. If the application is written using .NET Framework 3.5, SvcUtil.exe references DateTimeOffset automatically."*

But not sure what to make of it..

I used svcutil option /targetClientVersion:version35 and it didn't generate definition for DateTimeOffset. But my application is targeting .net 4.0 and I am not sure what else will break if target version 3.5, though I think it should be fine because .net4.0 is backward compatible with .net 3.5.

Comment: Are you using StyleCop?

Comment: yes. But the question is why DateTimeOffset is treated differently than other .net types. I don't see new type being generated for Guid etc.

Comment: _conficts_ is not in the dictionary: please double check your error message.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given above

> I used svcutil option **/targetClientVersion:version35** and it didn't generate definition for DateTimeOffset. But my application is targeting .net 4.0 and I am not sure what else will break if target version 3.5, though I think it should be fine because .net4.0 is backward compatible with .net 3.5.

For further documentation on this topic see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx.

I think that the intention behind the value **version35** is *version 3.5 and above*. You have to rethink only in case you like to use a .Net framework with a lower version.